# Не создается строка в таблице, если нет никаких в ней данных

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
INSERT INTO businesses_stats (Biz_id, Biz_Date) \
        SELECT '1', CURDATE() FROM businesses_stats WHERE \
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM businesses_stats WHERE Biz_Date = CURDATE() AND) LIMIT 1;
```

Вот такой запрос.
Необходимо, чтобы если не существовало  подобной строки - создавало новую.
Все работает при условии, если хотя бы одна строка есть в таблице. Как переделать запрос?

Comment: Это не может работать, потому что если в таблице скажем 10 строк и строки с указанными в not exists условиями нет, то запрос вернет все 10 строк, так как подзапрос не коррелированный, т.е. никак не зависит от основного запроса. Используйте в FROM основного запроса не эту таблицу, а какую нибудь другую, в которой гарантированно есть ровно 1 строка. Во многих БД такая специальная таблица называется DUAL

Comment: Достаточно создать уникальный индекс по полю `Biz_Date` и использовать простейшее `INSERT INTO businesses_stats (Biz_id, Biz_Date) SELECT 1, CURDATE();`. Уникальный индекс обеспечит требуемое условие лучше, чем подзапрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike был прав, именно Dual необходимо было использовать.
Что касается уникального индекса, про который сказал Akina, тут не все так просто. Дата может повторяться. необходимо сделать не только один уникальный столбец, но и второй.
Uniq Biz ID + Uniq Biz Date
Только такая строка может создаться.
Так что, с Dual все работает идеально.
Спасибо за ответы.
Вот такой запрос получился

```
INSERT INTO `businesses_stats` (`Biz_id`, `Biz_Date`) 
        SELECT '1', CURDATE() FROM DUAL 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `businesses_stats` 
        WHERE `Biz_id`='1' AND `Biz_Date`= CURDATE() LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: *именно Dual необходимо было использовать* В MySQL никакой DUAL нафиг не нужен - чай, не OracleDB...